# Weight of sphere in kerosene

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, density, fluid-statics

Two identically charged spheres are suspended by strings of equal length. When they immersed in kerosene, the angle between their string remains the same as it was in the air. Find the density of the spheres.

Comment: This question looks incomplete. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Buddy this is mot home work..... i can't derive then what wrong in it.....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the particle is in equilibrium $F_net=0$

In vacuum
$F_{vac}=T\sin(\theta)$

$mg=T\cos(\theta)$

$\frac{F_{vac}}{mg} = \tan(\theta)$.... (1)

Inside the liquid the spheres experience a bouyant force upward($U$)
Since it is also in equilibrium

$F_{med}=T'\sin(\theta)$

$mg-U=T'\cos(\theta)$

$\frac{F_{med}}{mg-U}=\tan(\theta)$..... (2)

From 1 & 2 we get

$F_{med}\times mg=F_{vac}\times(mg-U)$

$\frac{F_vac}{F_med}=\frac{mg}{mg-U}=\epsilon_r$

$\epsilon_r=\frac{P_s}{P_s-P_l}$

{Density of sphere/Density of sphere- Density of liquid)

Hence $P_s=\epsilon_r\times\frac{P_l}{1-\epsilon_r}$

Comment: how we can derive the weight in kerosene medium W' = W [1 - density of kerosene /density of sphere]
That I can not derive. I want to derive this eqation.